# I want to create a makefile without specifying filenames in it

Tags: c, makefile

I have 3 .c files and a makefile to be created for those three files without specifying the filenames in the makefile. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want make to do with this makefile?

Comment: Google for 'passing parameters to make'

Comment: Note that one can usefully run `make` for some purposes without any makefile at all.

Comment: If your files are `file1.c`, `file2.c` and `file3.c` and they each make a separate program, you don't even need a `makefile` to be able say `make file1 file2 file3` and have the programs compiled.  Or you can add settings, like setting warning options in CFLAGS, in the makefile.

Comment: Some implementations of `make` have built-in functions like `wildcard()`. Please check your documentation.

Comment: Check out pattern rules: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples